# Mysql Query is not working in edited jTable code, why?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, jquery-jtable

**I'm using this example:** [www.jtable.org](http://www.jtable.org)

I've downloaded the jTable PHP version. I then edited the script. The jTable simple version **is working**, but my **edited** version **isn't**.

I can create a list, but I can't add a row; this code is causing problems. However, PHP doesn't display any error messages.

```
else if($_GET["action"] == "create")
{
    //Insert record into database
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO veriler(bolge, sehir, firma, adres, tel, web) VALUES('" . $_POST["bolge"] . "', '" . $_POST["sehir"] . "', '" . $_POST["firma"] . "', '" . $_POST["adres"] . "', '" . $_POST["tel"] . "', '" . $_POST["web"] . "'");

    //Get last inserted record (to return to jTable)
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM veriler WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();");
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);


    //Return result to jTable
    $jTableResult = array();
    $jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
    $jTableResult['Record'] = $row;

    print json_encode($jTableResult);
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: try adding this to the top to display errors: 
`error_reporting( E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE );
ini_set( 'display_errors', '1' );`

Comment: Echo out the content of your SQL statements, and run them in the database? Do they work? Also, you should look at moving to `PDO` or `mysqli_`, as they let you write more secure code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this line, there is a problem:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO veriler(bolge, sehir, firma, adres, tel, web) VALUES('" . $_POST["bolge"] . "', '" . $_POST["sehir"] . "', '" . $_POST["firma"] . "', '" . $_POST["adres"] . "', '" . $_POST["tel"] . "', '" . $_POST["web"] . "'");
```

The format for the INSERT query is:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, etc) VALUES (value1, value2, etc);
```

**You missed a closing parenthesis for the VALUES part.**

To improve your code, you can do something like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("YOUR QUERY") or die('ERROR: '.mysql_error());
```

And please read on [SQL Injection](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).

Comment: www.jtable.org is not my own code write. If you want need a example please look jtable.org download class. Thanks for help!

Comment: Now i tryed your fix, and worked. THANK YOU! You are a big guy!

Answer (score 3):

here is the problem   you forget the `)`

```
 $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO veriler(bolge, sehir, firma, adres, tel, web) 
                       VALUES('" . $_POST["bolge"] . "', '" . $_POST["sehir"] . "', '" . $_POST["firma"] . "', '" . $_POST["adres"] . "', '" . $_POST["tel"] . "', '" . $_POST["web"] . "'");
```

use

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO veriler(bolge, sehir, firma, adres, tel, web) VALUES
                         ('{$_POST["bolge"]}', '{$_POST["sehir"] }' , '{$_POST["firma"]}' , '{$_POST["adres"] }', '{$_POST["tel"]}', '{$_POST["web"]}' )" ) ;
```

Comment: Thank you for reply but its true and when i remove ";" this is giving error and dont loading list data.

I using ajax codes and its not giving mysql error..

Comment: @FurkanKadıoğlu sorry i was mistaken check this out now

Answer (score 2):

first of all you can reduce one query of `last_inset_id()`

```
else if($_GET["action"] == "create")
{
    //Insert record into database
    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO veriler(bolge, sehir, firma, adres, tel, web) VALUES('" . $_POST["bolge"] . "', '" . $_POST["sehir"] . "', '" . $_POST["firma"] . "', '" . $_POST["adres"] . "', '" . $_POST["tel"] . "', '" . $_POST["web"] . "'"));
//Get last inserted record (to return to jTable)
//check youe result query you are missing something here
$id=mysql_insert_id();
//this will automatically give you last id 

//Return result to jTable
$jTableResult = array();
$jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
$jTableResult['id'] = $id;
$jTableResult['Record'] = $row;
$jTableResult['aderes'] = $_POST['adres'];
//and so on 
print json_encode($jTableResult);
```

}